# subdomain-fu not working in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, subdomain-fu

In my gem file i have added gem `'subdomain-fu', '1.0.0.beta2'` . Then I did `bundle install`.  I tried to print <%= current_subdomain %> but I got `undefined local variable or method`current_subdomain'` . Why am I getting this error?

I have also restarted my nginx server and unicorn too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a gem to add sudomains in Rails.

Here's some code I've sucesffully added into one of my apps.

In your `routes.rb` add the following:

```
constraints subdomain: false do
  root to: 'landings#index'
end

constraints subdomain: 'my' do
  get '/', to: 'users#show', as: 'app_root'

  resources :users
  resources :games do
    collection do
      get :search, to: 'games#search', as: :search
    end
  end
end
```

The following gives me:

```
                root GET    /                                                              landings#index
            app_root GET    /                                                              users#show {:subdomain=>"my"}
               users GET    /users(.:format)                                               users#index {:subdomain=>"my"}
                     POST   /users(.:format)                                               users#create {:subdomain=>"my"}
            new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                           users#new {:subdomain=>"my"}
           edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                                      users#edit {:subdomain=>"my"}
                user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                           users#show {:subdomain=>"my"}
                     PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                                           users#update {:subdomain=>"my"}
                     PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                           users#update {:subdomain=>"my"}
                     DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                           users#destroy {:subdomain=>"my"}
        search_games GET    /games/search(.:format)                                        games#search {:subdomain=>"my"}
               games GET    /games(.:format)                                               games#index {:subdomain=>"my"}
                     POST   /games(.:format)                                               games#create {:subdomain=>"my"}
            new_game GET    /games/new(.:format)                                           games#new {:subdomain=>"my"}
           edit_game GET    /games/:id/edit(.:format)                                      games#edit {:subdomain=>"my"}
                game GET    /games/:id(.:format)                                           games#show {:subdomain=>"my"}
                     PATCH  /games/:id(.:format)                                           games#update {:subdomain=>"my"}
                     PUT    /games/:id(.:format)                                           games#update {:subdomain=>"my"}
                     DELETE /games/:id(.:format)                                           games#destroy {:subdomain=>"my"}
```

The catch with this method is that for subdomains routes, you have to use `search_games_path(subdomain: 'mysubdomainname')` or `search_games_url (which automatically points to your subdomain)`

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 comes with functionality built in so you dont need to use old gems such as subdomain_fu.

To get the current subdomain in rails 4, simply do:

```
<%= request.subdomain %>
```